# How to display an ImageView progressively down from top to bottom

Tags: android, android-imageview

is there a way to display an ImageView progressively from top to down,
like this:

[image]

Sorry for the crappy animation.

Comment: You want the `ImageView` to animate that way by itself? Or you want to do it as the user does something?

Comment: not sure what the difference is but I would say by itself

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with android animations, but one(a little hackish) way is to wrap the image in a `ClipDrawable` and animate its `level` value. For example:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/clip_source" />
```

Where `clip_source` is a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_own_drawable"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Then in code you would have:

```
// a field in your class
private int mLevel = 0;

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable.setLevel(0);
mHandler.post(animateImage);
```

The `animateImage` is a `Runnable` object:

```
private Runnable animateImage = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doTheAnimation();
        }
    };
```

and the `doTheAnimation` method:

```
private void doTheAnimation() {
    mLevel += 1000;
    mImageDrawable.setLevel(mLevel);
    if (mLevel <= 10000) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(animateImage, 50);
    } else {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(animateImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! What is mHandler in that case?

Comment: @ibiza It's a `Handler` instance, `Handler mHandler = new Handler();`.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to make this method work, I always see the full image

Comment: @ibiza Some parts from my original code didn't show up. See if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have a somewhat satisfying result now, however the animation goes from bottom to top, do you know why? Best regards

Comment: got it, changed the android:gravity="bottom" of the xml drawable to android:gravity="top"

Comment: +10 buddy..keep going. here is a official doc: http://apiminer.org/doc/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable