# Simple ImageView color animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

Hi I am relatively new to Android, and I would like, if possible, some guidelines or suggestions on where to search in order to solve my issue. Apparently, I do not possess the reputation to post images, therefore I'll try to explain it as well as i can.

Let's say I have an empty bottle, and once this fragment/activity is called i want to introduce an animation that will gradually and vertically (from bottom to top) start filling this imageView with water.

Any thoughts or directions,

Thanks a lot and in advance!

Comment: You can do this by using a custom ProgressBar. Even more simpler. Added an answer below on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having 2 images of the bottle?
One (on foreground) would be an empty bottle with transparency
The (on background) second one would be the "shape of the liquid"

when your activity starts, get the background one and animate it like posted on this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127985/4232337

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, seems like it is what i want to do more or less. Going to try this and accept your answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a custom `ProgressBar`. Even more simpler

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="30"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_clip" >
        </ProgressBar>
```

**progress_bar_clip.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom" >
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </bitmap>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

You don't have do load any animations. Just use a handler and increment the progress bar by 1.

```
final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(bar.getProgress() != 100) {
                    bar.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
                }
            }
        };;

        handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: I had to use something similar in one of the apps that I made, and came up with this quick solution. Glad it helps. 

Also make sure, you set a empty glass background to the `ProgressBar` and in `android:id="@android:id/progress"` set a filled glass drawable. That way, it actually looks like the water is filling in the glass.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks again for your tips and all the solution is great :D! I have a follow-up question, when the animation starts it shows portion of the picture, i set the progress to 0 and tried some other stuff, but it doesnt't seem to have any effect, any immediate thoughts. Thanks again so much!

Comment: @thanosChatz In the XML, set the progress to 0 => `android:progress="0"`